# Aspose formula having a column index changing issue

Tags: c#, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I am using aspose 8.0.1.0 in a windows (C#) application. When I set the formula for a column as

```
sheet1.Cells[3, 2].Formula = "='Supplies - Factor'!G757222";
```

the formula automatically changed to

```
"='Supplies - Factor'!G36326"
```

I have verified it using debugger. If I set the formula  to

> "='Supplies - Factor'!G757222"

Then it automatically changed to

> "='Supplies - Factor'!G36326"

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the latest version/fix: Aspose.Cells for .NET v8.9.0 (you may download it [here](http://www.aspose.com/downloads/cells/net/new-releases/aspose.cells-for-.net-8.9.0/)). Please try to save the file to XLSX or other advanced MS Excel file formats (instead of older XLS). I have tested your scenario/case using the following sample code, it works fine and the formula is inserted correctly and does not change.
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
//Instantiate a new workbook
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
        //Get the default worksheet (first worksheet)
        Worksheet sheet1 = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        sheet1.Name = "Supplies - Factor";
        //Enter a value to the cell
        sheet1.Cells["G757222"].PutValue("Testin...");
        //Add the formula to the C4 cell
        sheet1.Cells[3, 2].Formula = "='Supplies - Factor'!G757222";
        //Save the Excel file
        workbook.Save("e:\\test2\\out1formulatest1.xlsx", SaveFormat.Xlsx);
```

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thank you @Amjad. This issue is fixed in the latest version.